# adding new value to existing string value using it's index or

Tags: c#, .net

U have string which containes url link like

```
var link = "/MyAwesomePage.htm";
```

this link var ofcourse holds dynamic value and I want programmatically change this string in this case into `"/MyAwesomePage_andMyVeryShortComment.htm"`

Comment: Have you tried to take a look at `String.Split` method or `Regex` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it that way

```
var link = "/MyAwesomePage.htm";

var index = link.LastIndexOf(".htm"); // or LastIndexOf(".") for every extensions
if (index != -1)
{
   link = link.Insert(index, "_andMyVeryShortComment");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var link = "/MyAwesomePage.htm";
link = link.Insert(link.IndexOf("."), "_andMyVeryShortComment");
```

I'm not sure I've got what you mean. But I hope this can help

Comment: You have to be careful with this one. You could end up with an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if the '.' doesn't exist in the string.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably quite a few ways to do this, but one that I would use is:

```
var link = "/MyAwesomePage.htm";

var index = link.IndexOf(".htm");

if (index > 0)
  link = link.Insert(index, "_andMyVeryShortComment");
```

This way, you can insert just before the .htm and you are also protected if the string does not contain '.htm'.